# simple solr query does not work - what do I miss?

Tags: solr

I am desperate because a simple solr query does not work as I expect it to work.
Maybe I miss something? May be my solr configuration is missing something? Please have a quick look.

I work with solr version 7.6 and use the built in query tool from the management GUI.

This is a result showing four simple documents.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"id:product_*",
      "fl":"id,user_s",
      "_":"1567779605014"}},
  "response":{"numFound":4,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"product_1",
        "user_s":"rjKv1opWMLYQ"},
      {
        "id":"product_5",
        "user_s":"rjKv1opWMLYQ"},
      {
        "id":"product_7",
        "user_s":"plOG1Pv0gQvk"},
      {
        "id":"product_8",
        "user_s":"plOG1Pv0gQvk"}]
  }}
```

I would like to query for documents with either ID=product_1 or user_s=rjKv1opWMLYQ. I expect to get 2 results, the document with id=product_1 and the one with id=product_5. But with the query string `id:product_1 OR user_s:rjKv1opWMLYQ` I get the following.

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":1,
    "params":{
      "q":"id:product_1 OR user_s:rjKv1opWMLYQ",
      "fl":"id,user_s",
      "_":"1567779605014"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"product_1",
        "user_s":"rjKv1opWMLYQ"}]
  }}
```

Exactly the same as with the query strings `id:product_1 user_s:rjKv1opWMLYQ`, `id:product_1 AND user_s:rjKv1opWMLYQ`, `id:product_1 && user_s:rjKv1opWMLYQ` and `id:product_1 || user_s:rjKv1opWMLYQ`.

The field schema for both fields is as follows.

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<dynamicField name="*_s" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true" multiValued="false" />
```

The general types schema is here: https://pastebin.com/Hs1Jnrin

The general fields schema is here: https://pastebin.com/N91bDXcE

What is going on here?

Comment: Please post your solrConfig as well. And also the queries that are logged in the Solr logs.

Comment: Could you include the response that you get if you check the "debugQuery" checkbox in the Admin screen (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/query-screen.html#query-screen) when you run your query? With debugQuery we should be able to see how is Solr parsing your query (look under the debug node of the response)

Comment: Another thing to try is to check the "edismax" checkbox on that page and see if you get different results.